# .htaccess multi rule rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess

Basically, I want to have the path:

**store.com/[category_name]/[subcategory_name]**

so -> **store.com/computer/hard-drive**

This one is works:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ products.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2 [L]
```

And then I need each product details, lets say "wd1tera" to have path: **store.com/computer/wd1tera**

Real path is: product.php?id=[number]

This website will have absolute category and subcategory, and always have product path under category, even it's part of subcategory. But of course we will have several category names, not just "computer".

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the product ID is alphanumeric then there's no way of distinguishing between those two rules, so you'd need an identifier of some kind.

I would suggest the following URLs as they add more descriptive as to what each page means:

```
http://www.domain.com/category/{CAT}/{SUB}
http://www.domain.com/view/{CAT}/{ID}
```

If however the product ID was numeric only, then you could do:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ product.php?id=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ products.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2
```

Comment: uhmm... I think I will use your suggestion then. Product details will be: store.com/details/wd1tera
But also need to change the breadcrumbs T_T